# In Qtranslate plugin, it does not show multilanguage slidet title. how to make it working?

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

hi am using the ***qtranslate*** plugin. everything is working,but slider title does not show the multilingual like as English and Russian language....how to solve this problem?

WordPress version 3.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1.) Make slider title use qTranslate language tags like this:

```
<!--:en-->english title<!--:--><!--:de-->german title<!--:-->
```

2.) locate where the slider title is used in the template and use `_e()` function like this

```
 _e($title)
```

To learn more about `_e()` function check [Translating Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology) article.

Comment: thanks for the help... i also post another question regarding this plugin... please help me if you can. thanks again for the help :)